# saving to temp folder in php apache

Tags: php, apache, tmp

I repeatedly get the following error when I try to save a processed document to a temp folder using php. (btw I running apache on my local machine)

> "Warning: DOMDocument::save(/tmp/lecture.xml) [domdocument.save]:
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /Users/JCWitt/WebPages/plaoul/text/textdisplay.php on line 278"

A couple of questions here:

1) When I tell the server to save the file in `/tmp/` is it looking for a folder in the ServerRoot or the DocumentRoot?

2) Second can I do something in httpd.conf to give php permissions to save files? And can you tell me what I might add?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 'Permission denied' hints to access rights to the directory. Have you checked them?

Comment: sort of -- but things bring me to first question -- which directory? -- the tmp dir from the ServerRoot or the tmp dir from the DocumentRoot

Comment: `/tmp/` is a relative path which will be relative to your current working directory. You can find out what that directory is with the `getcwd()` function. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php. But what do you mean by 'sort of' checking your folder permissions?